# Right aligned text in a cell to overflow to the left in Excel?

Tags: excel, alignment, overflow

I have an email address in an excel cell on my invoice, if I left align it, the text will overflow to the right. I need the email address right aligned and overflow to the left cell, but can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

I dont want to move the columns, coz it will affect everything under it and I don't plan to merge the cells either coz my code wont work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try **Wrap text**? Here is the [documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/wrap-text-in-a-cell-HP005199835.aspx)

Comment: No text wrap, coz it makes the cell height bigger and i dont want to shift anything. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: It works for me, as long as there isn't anything in the cell to the left.

Comment: Solved it myself now. I just added a bottom alight to it and it worked!